# cause by NullPointerException : Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[ModuleName]] IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, tomcat8

I have configured already java sdk, catalina setup, add supporting framework (maven, spring mvc and spring security) and maven is also build success in the project. But the above is the error I have encountered after running the Project in tomcat server in intellij. Can you help me what could be missing in my configuration?
Also see: [Apache Tomcat run configuration.JPG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jh3EY.jpg)

```
24-Jul-2017 23:35:47.051 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/MyProject]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1702)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:431)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[2017-07-24 11:35:47,067] Artifact MyProject:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:346)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.nokia.care.MyProjectui.init.Initializer.onStartup(Initializer.java:31)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:180)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5178)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 42 more

```
24-Jul-2017 23:35:47.054 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] 
org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke Exception invoking method manageApp
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/MyProject]]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:756)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1702)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:431)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:346)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

24-Jul-2017 23:35:47.057 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] 
org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke Exception invoking method createStandardContext
javax.management.RuntimeOperationsException: Exception invoking method manageApp
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:308)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:431)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:346)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/MyProject]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:756)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1702)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    ... 33 more

Comment: Is your project Maven based? https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-176239 may be the case.

Comment: Yes, the project is checkout from svn then is imported as a maven project. The nullpointerexception is the AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext)().

Comment: I am not sure but i think it is a different case.

Comment: Do you mean that you see all the required jars in the [artifact](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/artifacts.html)?

Comment: in MyProject\WEB-INF\lib i could see the jars. is there a specfic jar file that i should look for?

Comment: Look in the artifact output directory.

Comment: By the way, does -Dspring.profiles.active=dev helps when I add it in the VM options of tomcat? thanks

Comment: "Look in the artifact output directory. – CrazyCode"
.
.
.
as i have checked what i can only see in the output is the created .war artifact. sorry i am new to maven and intellij not sure if this is what you are referring to, thanks.

Comment: .war is a zip archive, unpack it and see what's inside. Does the deployment work if you build the artifact via Maven and deploy it outside of IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: yes, build is successful when run in maven. When .war is unzip, it contained  files such as - META-INF, resources, WEB-INF and wulf.

Comment: error was caused because of the latest intellij version 14. when adding framework support of spring mvc, an existing web.xml file is populated by an application context which is at first a null pointer causing this error.